# OpenSSH: Cannot disable weak algorithms

Tags: configuration, openssh, cryptography

I am on an RHEL 7.5 and I would like to disable weak crypto algorithms (i.e. CBC-based ciphers, weak MACs, etc.).

Hence, I modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, especially the lines starting with `ciphers` and `macs` to exclude the respective weak ciphers.

As an example: I removed `aes128-cbc`,`aes192-cbc`, `aes256-cbc` from the `Ciphers` line in sshd_config and restarted the SSH server.

So, when testing the new configuration there is a difference between connecting from within the system that provides the SSH service (i.e. `ssh -vv localhost`) the weak ciphers are not offered anymore (I look at the `peer server KEXINIT proposal` section). What is strange is, when connecting from an external system to the target (i.e. `ssh -vv target_ip`), the cbc-based ciphers are offered again.

Is there some sort of second configuration file that overrides sshd_config or what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got solved. The underlying problem was due to an intermediate firewall that was acting as a transparent SSH proxy. The SSH proxy was accepting the weak ciphers, which was transparent to the client.

Comment: what you did to solve that? Did you disable the firewall? or did you configure it? What was the firewall?